# Best way to convert childNodes to array in underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to convert Element's childNodes to an array in javascript.

How do I convert childNodes into array? Any cool idea?

Comment: aPara = _.map(elMiddleList.childNodes); I found it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with _.toArray()

html part:

```
<div id="testdiv"><div id="t1"></div><div id="t2"></div><div id="t3"></div><div id="t4"></div><div id="t5"></div></div>
```

js:

```
var td = document.getElementById("testdiv");
console.log(_.toArray(td.childNodes));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the need for underscore, this comes to mind: `[].concat.apply([],nodelist)`

However it won't work in all browsers due to older ones requiring an array rather than an array-like object, so I just use this:

```
function toarray(obj) {
    var l = obj.length, i, out = [];
    for(i=0; i<l; i++) out[i] = obj[i];
    return out;
}
```

This is probably the simplest way and the most compatible too.